# Android Glide BlurTransformation

Tags: java, android, picasso, android-glide

Hi I cannot get Glide BlurTransformation to work, I used Picasso before as you can see on the image, but I get an error with Glide, I also tried to use .apply(bitmapTransform(BlurTransformation(20, 3))) but same error, so how can I get it to work with the newest version of Glide and BlurTransmation?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFwES.jpg

```
                                Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                        .load(rCoverImg)
                                        .transform(new BlurTransformation(getApplicationContext(), 20, 3))
                                        .centerCrop()
                                        .into(mBinding.profileCover);

                                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                                        .load(rCoverImg)
                                        .transform(new BlurTransformation(getApplicationContext(), 20, 3))
                                        .into(mBinding.profileCover);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `BlurTransformation()` required two parameters First is `radius` and second is `sampling`

check this screen shot for source code `BlurTransformation()`

[image]

### if You want to use `Glide` the use this

```
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8FFo.jpg?s=328&g=1")
            .transform(new BlurTransformation( 20, 3))
            .centerCrop()
            .into((mBinding.profileCover);
```

Make sure you have correct imports for `Glide`

```
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import jp.wasabeef.glide.transformations.BlurTransformation;
```

> UPDATE

```
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8FFo.jpg")
            .apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop())
            .transform(new BlurTransformation( 20, 2))
            .into(myImageView);
```

### If you want use `Picasso` then

Use this

```
Picasso.get()
       .load(rCoverImg)
       .transform(new BlurTransformation(getApplicationContext(), 20, 3))
       .into(mBinding.profileCover);
```

Instead of this

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
       .load(rCoverImg)
       .transform(new BlurTransformation(getApplicationContext(), 20, 3))
       .into(mBinding.profileCover);
```

Comment: I dont want to use picasso anymore, and yes I know I should use get instead of with, I used a old version of picasso before, so I didnt edit it yet :)

Comment: It also required to cast Context, but then I do that I get this error: https://imgur.com/a/TvKhnbA

Comment: @JonathanNet i think you have wrong imports, please check updated answer i have added corrects imports

Comment: @JonathanNet **FYI**  no need to pass `getApplicationContext()` inside `new BlurTransformation(getApplicationContext(), 20, 3)` please read my answer carefully

Comment: Yeah It was the import from Picasso that fucked it up, now it works, but I cannot use .centerCrop(); in it, then it dont work anymore.

Comment: @JonathanNet try to use `.apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop())` check my updated answer